# lvalues in the ISO C11 standard

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11, lvalue

§ 6.3.2.1:2 of ISO/IEC 9899:2011, i.e. the “ISO C11 standard”, says:

> 2 Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the unary `&`
>   operator, the `++` operator, the `--` operator, or the left operand of the
>   `.` operator or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not have
>   array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object
>   (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called lvalue conversion. If the
>   lvalue has qualified type, the value has the unqualified version of
>   the type of the lvalue; additionally, if the lvalue has atomic type,
>   the value has the non-atomic version of the type of the lvalue;
>   otherwise, the value has the type of the lvalue. If the lvalue has an
>   incomplete type and does not have array type, the behavior is
>   undefined. If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage
>   duration that could have been declared with the register storage class
>   (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not
>   declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been
>   performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.

But isn't a dereferenced pointer also an lvalue, just like the pointer itself? E.g. `int *ptr; ptr = malloc(…); *ptr = 1`

So why is the `*` operator not mentioned – or do I confuse something here?

Comment: What is it you think should be in that paragraph? In `*ptr`, `ptr` is an lvalue. Then is is, per 6.3.2.1 2, converted to its value. Then `*` operates on it, producing an lvalue for the-pointed to object. Then `*ptr` is the left operand of an assignment operator, so it remains an lvalue. Then the assignment assigns `1` to the pointed-to object.

Comment: The paragraph you quote is about how lvalues behave  ,  not about how lvalues are created  (the latter is where the `*` in `*ptr` would be discussed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing section 6.5.3.2p4, which discusses the semantics of indirection operator `*`:

> The unary
>   `*` operator denotes indirection.  If the operand points to a function, the result is a  function  designator;  **if  it  points  to  an 
>   object,  the  result  is  an  lvalue  designating  the object.**   If 
>   the  operand  has  type  "pointer  to type",  the  result  has 
>   type  "type".   If  an invalid  value  has  been  assigned  to 
>   the  pointer,  the  behavior  of  the  unary
>   `*` operator  is undefined.

The operator itself is defined to produce an lvalue.